# Main HTML Element Shrinks Smaller Than Page

Tags: html, css

All of the pages on my site scale properly except one. It has a wide table. When I minimize my window the page scales accordingly, but once this table reaches a certain minimum width it can't get any smaller and a scroll bar appears at the bottom of the screen. This is fine, however the main `<html>` tag scales to the size of my screen, not taking the overflowing table into consideration. So when looking at the small window it looks fine, the `navbar` fills the screen and there is a scroll bar to slide right and view the rest of the table. However, once you scroll to the right, the `<html>` tag ends and therefore my `navbar` is cut off.

How can I make it so that when the screen is small, the main `<html>` tag doesn't shrink smaller than the overflowing table? I will then need to make the `navbar` reactive and fit the size of the screen, not the `<html>` tags as I dont want users to have to scroll to the right to view the whole `navbar`.

Or perhaps the `<html>` tags should scale to the size of the window and be cut off when a user scrolls right (I don't know), but then I would need my `navbar` to extend outside of the `<html>` element to fit the page if it's being scrolled to the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> # this div is the size of the screen and the expanded table falls outside of it
    <body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"> # this navbar fits the screen width (good), but when a user scrolls to the right to view the large table the navbar ends and there is just blank space to the right of it
    </header>
    <main role="main">
    <div>
        <table> # this table expands wider than the screen
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>two</td>
                <td>three</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've Googled a lot and tried many different things (setting width, overflow, display:flex, etc) but can't get it working.

Thank you.

Comment: Please produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so viewers can analyze the code

Comment: Okay, I added it. I havent changed the css for those classes (the navbar uses bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `<html>` tag uses `block` as its `display` property (`display: block`). This means that the element will take up `100%` of its container's `width` (`width: 100%`) by default. Since technically it does not have a container, it is relative to the viewport. You can use `display: inline-block` on the `<html>`, `<body>`, the table's container or all of them so that it will respond the content's width.

```
element {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo**:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.really-long-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="really-long-content">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
</div>
```

**VERSUS** what you probably have now:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
}

.really-long-content {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="really-long-content">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
</div>
```

Simply examine the borders that I used as visual aid to assess width.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. This seems like exactly what I need, however when I apply it to my ```html``` div it doesn't change anything (setting ```display:none``` makes the page blank so it is loading the css properly).

Comment: you need to check the parent and ancestors of your table element as well - not just the html tag